# Powershell -like won't compare to variable

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, I can do this:

```
    $Useraccount = Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like "*Smith*"}
```

and find some user(s), but when I do this:

```
    $namefilter = "Smith"
    $Useraccount = Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like "*$namefilter*"}
```

nothing is found. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Filter` looks like it accepts a script block like Where-Object, but it's actually a string.  If you use the curly braces syntax, it tends to treat it like a literal string, so variables won't expand.

Try:

```
$Useraccount = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$namefilter*'"
```

Comment: Or create a subexpression ala `-Filter { Name -like "*$($namefilter)*"}` and it will then expand the variable.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Subexpressions don't work for me on v4.0.  `Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like "*$($namefilter)*" }` returns no results while `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$namefilter*'"` returns about 90.  Like I said, I think it gets treated as a literal string.

Comment: Huh, I could swear that it used to work. You're right, it doesn't work.

Comment: The only way I could get away with that sort of stuff while using a script block was to pass parameters and use args.. string is just easier. `[scriptblock]::Create("name -like '*$namefilter*'")`